# Every man has fought against the Starks

Tags: dialogue, game-of-thrones

In episode 2 of season 8 of *Game of Thrones*, Tyrion says, while drinking in front of the fireplace, that every man there has fought against the Starks. Brienne is present there, so taking Tyrion’s word choices literally, is it really true that *every* man there has actually fought against the Starks at some point of time?

1. Tormund fought Jon Snow (although he is half Stark, though Tyrion does not know that).
2. Jaime fought against Robb during the War of the Five Kings.
3. Tyrion I think also fought during that battle and if he did, perhaps Pod as Tyrion’s squire can be thought of as fighting as well.

But Ser Davos never fought any Stark.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "fought".  Ser Davos was Hand of the King for Stannis Baratheon when Stannis had declared himself the rightful King and was looking at all the other Kings including Rob Stark as rebels.

Comment: Good point. But I do not think “fought” is the same as “being hostile to”. I am looking for active conflict, though that possibly excludes Pod.

Comment: @iandotkelly and that logic then also includes Brienne for Renly.

Comment: He says - "It's strange, isn't it? ALMOST everyone here's fought the Starks at one time or another." - according to this site, which jibes with my own recollection - 
https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=game-of-thrones&episode=s08e02

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Tyrion uses a key word that absolves him of being inaccurate - *almost*.

> It's strange, isn't it? Almost everyone here's fought the Starks at one time or another.

He also says "everyone" and not every man, however Brienne did in fact fight Stark bannermen while attempting to escort Jaime south.

Comment: She also originally start in Renly's camp, so technically _against_ the Starks (and everyone else for that matter).